# How do we write data into firebase real time database? Even though read/write is enabled, just doesn't seem to work

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have created a sign up page that gets the user's email, username, fullname, password and profilepicture. Problem is that firebase authentication works perfectly and also I managed to upload the profile picture successfully to firebase storage. I just can't seem to write the other properties like fullname and username to the firebase REAL TIME DATABASE (Not firestore).

Read and write is already set to true:
Authentication works successfully
Image storage works successfully
Data Write to real time database is not working

No error is thrown. There is just no data being written
Using xcode 10.2.1

```
@objc func handleSignUp() {

        // properties
        guard let email = emailTextField.text else { return }
        guard let password = passwordTextField.text else { return }
        guard let fullName = fullNameTextField.text else { return }
        guard let username = usernameTextField.text?.lowercased() else { return }

        Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { (user, error) in

            // handle error
            if let error = error {
                print("Failed to create user with error: ", error.localizedDescription)
                return
            }

            // set profile image
            guard let profileImg = self.plusPhotoBtn.imageView?.image else { return }

            // upload data
            guard let uploadData = profileImg.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.3) else { return }

            // place image in firebase storage
            let filename = NSUUID().uuidString
            Storage.storage().reference().child("profile_images").child(filename).putData(uploadData)
            Storage.storage().reference().child("profile_images/\(filename).jpg").downloadURL(completion: { (url, error) in
                guard let profileImageUrl = url?.absoluteString else {return}
                guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else {return}
                let dictionaryValues = ["name": fullName,
                                        "username": username,
                                        "profileImageUrl": profileImageUrl]
                let values = [uid: dictionaryValues]
                Database.database().reference().child("users").updateChildValues(values, withCompletionBlock: { (error, ref) in

                    guard let mainTabVC = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController as? MainTabVC else { return }

                    // configure view controllers in maintabvc
                    mainTabVC.configureViewControllers()

                    // dismiss login controller
                    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                })

            })
        }
    }
```

Comment: You must be getting an error, print the error message and edit your question

Comment: True that. Just noticed that I wasn't printing the error :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sequence you're executing in your code is part the issue. You should really use the closure following putData to then work with the data you put.

Also, when you create a user, the closure will contain a user var to which you can get the uid from. So don't do this `guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid` as the user var is guaranteed to be valid.

Here's a generic template to work from

```
Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { (user, error) in

   // handle error
   if let error = error {
      print("Failed to create user with error: ", error.localizedDescription)
      return
   }
   .
   .
   .

   // Upload the file to the path "images/rivers.jpg"
   let ref = storageRef.putData(data, metadata: nil) { (metadata, error) in
       guard let metadata = metadata else {
           print("error while uploading")
           return
       }
       // Metadata contains file metadata such as size, content-type.
       let size = metadata.size
       storageRef.downloadURL { (url, error) in
           guard let downloadURL = url else {
               print("an error occured after uploading and then downloading")
               return
           }

           let validDownloadUrl = downloadURL.absoluteString
           let uid = user.uid
           let dictionaryValues = ["name": fullName,
                                   "username": username,
                                   "profileImageUrl": validDownloadUrl]
           //write out your firebase data with a key of uid
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Also a quick update. For some reason I can't call the user.uid. It only works if I use the currentuser.uid approach or I'll have to do user?.user.uid. Don't know why swift requires mentioning of user twice.